# Should I arch my back in a butterfly kick?

Tags: kicking, kung-fu

I don't have a problem with the takeoff and landing of my butterfly kick, but various people have suggested different way to perform the kick. Usually when I do the kick, I launch my lower body upwards and keep my head level.

I have heard others say to dip your head downwards more or to arch your back. When I do arch my back, I feel as though I have a little more lift and keep myself airborne better. I tighten my muscles more rather than let leap high (I have the natural ability to do so) and then let gravity take over.

Is there a "standard" to how the butterfly kick is done or is arching my back (among other slight variations) merely a stylistic difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time I've ever done a butterfly kick, I've arched my back. I've found that if I let my back be straight or slightly rounded, my hips drop and I lose the height needed to keep my body elevated enough for the kick to completely finish.

Unless your sifu specifically says otherwise, I'd go with what feels comfortable and allows you to complete the kick. I think the arch is a personal/stylistic difference, and unless it's grotesquely torqued, it is probably much less than you think.